# How to use jquery resize run funtion one time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use run 2 functions jquery when resize window. But I just want to do they one time. code can be like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var screenwidth=jQuery(window).width();
    if(screenwidth>991){
       dofunction1();
    }
    else{
      dofunction2();
    }
});
```

I want when screenwidth>991 do dofunction1() 1 time, and when screenwidth<=991 do dofunction2() 1 time. Hope your help!!

Comment: Can you clarify that you want these to run each time the window is resized, or if you only ever want to run them once, even if the window is resized later?

Comment: I want to run each time the window width change between >991 and <991. Sorry my english too bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind `resize` event

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

```
$(window).one('resize', function () {
    var screenwidth = jQuery(window).width();
    if (screenwidth > 991) {
        dofunction1();
    } else {
        dofunction2();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this before, but it just do like $(document).ready(). Mean when i resize window it do not work, so i have to refresh to run.